# Is it safe to use localStorage in web view app?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, local-storage

I'm using localStorage to save some datas in my android app,
my question is how can user erase those datas?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Build.VERSION_CODES.Kitkat) {
  localWebView.Settings.DatabasePath= "/data/data/" + localWebView.Context.PackageName + "/databases/";
}
```

using this code I'm trying to save my datas private.

Are those localStorage datas safe?

Comment: If they can execute localStorage.clear() no.

Comment: locakStorage stores the data in their device, they can view it if they try. they can also remove it.

Comment: There no area really "private" on a device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user can navigate to the directory where the local storage resides with a file explorer. It's not safe.

The recommended way to store sensitive information in Android is to use the  Keystore.

Reference [this article](https://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-keystore-store-passwords-sensitive-information-623779/) for more information and examples about the Keystore in general.

If you want access with Javascript, then take a look at [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/).

There are [several plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=keystore) to choose from that provide access to the Keystore in Android and the Keychain in iOS.

Comment: yeah, but I'm not storing any important data, what I want to know is if a user can delete localstorage without knowing it.

Comment: Okay. I misunderstood this part of the question. "Are those localStorage datas safe?"

Comment: Yes, the user can delete the apps local data by going to settings, applications, selecting you application and pressing on delete data or clear data. @Ajex_12